# Spark is loading some rows into one column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a table that looks like this

| keyword | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | A1 | 2021-01-01 |
| apple | A2 | 2021-01-02 |
| apple | A3 | 2021-01-02 |

After I save this table to S3 in TSV uncompressed, I check the distinct dates, which are correct (2020-01-01, 2020-01-2).

However, when I load the files from S3, for approximately .002% of the billion rows, the table now looks like this. The column values are all put into the first column, and the values are not guaranteed to be correct.

| keyword | id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple A1 2021-01-02 | null | null |
| apple A2 2021-01-01 | null | null |

while the vast majority of the table will look as intended. At the end, the distinct dates now are (2021-01-01, 2021-01-02, and null)

There is something strange going on with my load function, but I am not sure how to identify the root cause of this issue

My load function:

```
def load(s3Path: String): DataFrame = {
    sparkSession.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", true)
      .option("maxCharsPerColumn", MAX_CHARS_PER_COLUMN)
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .option("inferSchema", true)
      .load(s3Path)
  }
```

I have inferSchema set to true. Is that a possible root cause?

EDIT: I found my root cause.
Some keywords have a dangling quote, so it looks like "apple, and when Spark loads it, the row starting with an unclosed quote will be put into the keyword column.

Comment: Did you check the `delimiter` option?

Comment: @nimeresam The delimiter is set to \t and given that so many of the other rows are formatted correctly, the delimiter should be working

Comment: Can you specify the code of how you are writing the files to s3 and how you are reading/loading it?